# Calling a .py Function using DF from another file

Tags: python, function

I have created a file NBF_TextTranslation.py

```
spark = SparkSession.builder.getOrCreate()

df_TextTranslation = spark.read.format('delta').load(textTranslation_path)

def getMediumText(TextID, PlantName):
   df1 = spark.sql("SELECT TextID, PlantName, LanguageID, Short, Medium, Extended, Active FROM delta.`{0}` tt".format(textTranslation_path))
   df2 = df1.filter((df1.PlantName == PlantName) & (df1.TextID == TextID) & (df1.LanguageID == '1033') & (df1.Active == "True"))
    medium_Value = df2.select('Medium').first()[0]
   return medium_Value
```

I am calling my function from file DimDepartment_Amit.py

```
%run "../Functions/NBF_TextTranslation"
TextID = '106905303'
PlantName = 'BKIZ'
LanguageID = 1033

medium_value = getMediumText(TextID, PlantName)
print(medium_value)
```

This part is working but when i am calling it from SQL

```
sqlStatement =  "\
    SELECT\
        PlantName as BK_PlantName,\
        TextId,\
        getMediumText(TextId, PlantName) as DepartmentName,\
    FROM delta.`{0}`".format(src_path_Department)

df_stgDimDepartment = spark.sql(sqlStatement)

df_stgDimDepartment.show()
```

I am getting below error

Cannot resolve function `getMediumText` on search path [`system`.`builtin`, `system`.`session`, `spark_catalog`.`default`]. SQLSTATE: 42883; line 1 pos 167